# Android emulator is never disabling camera

Tags: android, android-camera, adt

As the title says, when I try to disable the camera, Android ignores it and as soon as I try to use some camera features, them work flawlessly.

[image]

And check the apps in the device:
[image]

Any tip to perform a full disabling of camera in android emulator?

Thanks!!
Edit: Still with no clues. I've tried Windows and Mac. Both happening the same.

Comment: I tend to avoid the standard Android emulator.  Try using Genymotion [http://www.genymotion.com/], the new version (1.3) supports the camera feature which can be enabled/disabled at any time without even restarting the emulator.

Comment: I hate it so much. It makes me register and login constantly. Not what I am looking for. Thanks by the way.

Comment: The Camera app is in the emulator image and can't be removed without recompiling the image. What those settings do is toggle the hardware feature, as queried by PackageManager. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I've some code which sets a IntentChoser. It "loops" for available galleries / cameras, and shows options to trigger any of those apps. And camera is always being shown there, and it shouldn't when the camera is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in your emulator goto -> **settings** -> **Apps** -> Show "**All**" -> there you
>   can see all Internal apps also listed like CALENDER, CAMERA etc... 
>   Choose **CAMERA** -> **Disable**

Also check in emulators there may be two applications for camera make sure you disable it too...

Hope this HELPS... :D

Comment: This worked. Notice that I "had" two cameras in my device. One was actually the Gallery, the other was the real camera.